# copy table with all constraint

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

how I would copy a table with all constraints?

I run `select * into myNewTable
from baseTable
where 1=0`

This copy a table but no with constraints

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the GUI management tool to create a script and then run that - you cannot do it directly - take a look [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/412a50fb-04bf-4476-8e22-cf04449e9351/copy-tables-with-all-constraints?forum=transactsql) (or [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18059/copy-complete-structure-of-a-table)) for relatively clear explanations.

Answer (score -4):

```
create table myNewTable like baseTable;
```

Comment: I guarantee that's wrong in SQL Server

Comment: Actully, it works but in Azure.